# Can't send mail with multiple recipients

Tags: python, email, attachment

I have a problem to send an attach to multiple recipients
I tried to do it without success, this is my code:

```py
def mail_semanal(msg_to, asunto="Reporte semanal", message="Reporte"):
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = 'postmaster@xxx.com'
    msg_to = msg_to
    msg['Subject'] = asunto
    
    msg.attach(MIMEText(message))
    mailserver = smtplib.SMTP('smtp-relay.xxx.com',587)
    mailserver.ehlo()
    mailserver.starttls()
    # adjunto
    filename = folder + reporte
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        message = MIMEText(f.read())
        message.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=reporte)
        msg.attach(message)
    user = 'postmaster@xxx.com'
    pwd = 'xxx'
    mailserver.ehlo()
    mailserver.login(user,pwd)
    mailserver.sendmail('smtp-relay.xxx.com',msg_to,msg.as_string())
    header = '\nTo:' + msg_to  + '\n' + 'From: ' + msg['From'] + '\n' + 'Subject:'+ msg['Subject'] +'\n'
    print(header)
    print ('enviado a las '+datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")+' !')
    mailserver.quit()
```

when I try to send to more than one recipient, it only sends to the first one in the list, this is the code of the main:

```
#Escribir consulta 
fnreporte.base_datos("select archivo_idreg,idtransferencia,round((montototal),2,1),c.diasremision idcliente_new,c.idcliente,c.razonsocial,t.fechadeposito from cdpnew..transferencias t left join clientes c on c.idcliente=t.idcliente where t.fechadeposito>'"+fecha+"'  and t.montototal<>0")


fecha=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m-%Y")
#escribir cabecera del excel con el siguiente formato ('c1,c2,c3,c4')
fnreporte.cvs('IDREG, IDTRANSFERENCIA, MONTOTOTAL, ID CLIENTE NUEVO, ID CLIENTE, RAZON SOCIAL, FECHA DEPOSITO',"Reporte_semanal_de_OP_PEI_Débito"+fecha+".csv")

#escribir destinatario
fnreporte.mail_semanal(['ZANAGA@LIVE.COM.AR,ivkanian@gmail.com'],"Reporte semanal de OP PEI - Débito "+fecha,"se adjunta el documento con el detalle")
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. What exactly is the problem? What happens when you run the code? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors?  See [ask].

Comment: Sorry, im new in the platform.